# How to find out H2 DB is running in memory

Tags: h2, in-memory-database

I know it's very basic question. But i have learned that H2 DB can run in-memory and like normal DB(e.g mysql). How can i find out that my H2 is running in-memory?

```
Multiple processes can access the same database without having to start the server manually.
To do that, append ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the database URL. You can use the same database URL
independent of whether the database is already open or not. **This feature doesn't work with in-
`memory databases.`**
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my researches, i found that we have to **change connection url** to use in memory DB.

### To use h2 on in-memory:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"
 value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
```

### To use h2 on HDD:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"
 value="jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"/>
```

### Explanations of Connection URLS:

> According to:[h2database.com](http://h2database.com/html/features.html)
>
> **DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1**
>
> > By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost. To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL. To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.
>
> **AUTO_SERVER=TRUE**
>
> > Multiple processes can access the same database without having to start the server manually. To do that, append ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the database URL. You can use the same database URL independent of whether the database is already open or not. This feature doesn't work with in-memory databases. Example database URL: